# Svelte how to pass store as a property?

Tags: svelte

I have a `Counter` component. Usually it's used with **simple value** properties. But in some cases I would like to pass one property as a **reactive** store.

How to do it? I would like to avoid creating two separate `Counter` for these two use cases.

Example, [play](https://svelte.dev/repl/4331ffc378d14e6e916668a16007dabc?version=3.38.3)

App.svelte

```svelte
<script>
  import Counter from "./Counter.svelte"
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
  
  const counter = writable(0)
  setTimeout(() => counter.update((v) => v + 1), 1000)
</script>

<Counter name="Cats" counter={counter}/>
<Counter name="Dogs" counter={1}/>
```

Counter.svelte

```velte
<script>
  export let name  
  export let counter
</script>

<div>{name} {counter}</div>
```

But it doesn't work and displayed as

```
Cats [object Object]
Dogs 1
```

And if I change it with `$counter` as `<div>{name} {$counter}</div>` then this won't work `<Counter name="Dogs" counter={1}/>`.

P.S.

If there are better ways to handle this problem possibly without the reactive store, please mention it.

Basically, I have some logic, that updates counter (data sent via websockets from server), and I want these changes to be propagated to the `Counter`, `store` seems like possible way to do it.

But in other places the `Counter` also used as plain component, without any data updates, and I don't want to overcomplicate these simple use cases.

So I'm looking for a simple way to use `Counter` in both contexts. To accept both simple and reactive property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[object Object]` value is the complete store and you only want the reactive `$counter` value so just give this one as the prop like:

```html
<Counter name="Cats" counter={$counter}/>
```

Here is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/52c28164d2bd4967924693a5fc8f3c46?version=3.38.3).

Comment: Thanks, yes. But If I do that, this example `<Counter name="Dogs" counter={1}/>` won't work

Comment: In the REPL `<Counter name="Dogs" counter={1}/>` render `Dogs 1` isn't that the intended result?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it works as expected! I misunderstood it at first.

Comment: This is not really passing the store to the child, but the value of the store at a given time.